# How can I call convert a piece of SVG to MVG via RMagick?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, rmagick, mvg

I want to convert a piece of SVG to MVG. Could I do something similar to this `convert msvg:pram.svg pram.mvg` using RMagick methods? I don't want to save the output in a file, but I want to have it in a variable in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In general, converting an image in one format to another format is as simple as making a copy of the image using a different suffix. https://rmagick.github.io/comtasks.html#convert

Use the to_blob method to get an image as a Ruby string:
https://rmagick.github.io/comtasks.html#blob